# is it good practice to add nodes and client folder to chef server template

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I am still learning about chef. I have bootstrapped and uploaded my server-template to remote repository. But am wondering if its safe to add `nodes` directory to `remote` repository as it contains exact server `passwords`

Here is an example node

```
{
  "environment":"production",
  "authorization": {
    "sudo": {
      // The password for the depliy user is set in data_bags/users/deploy.json
      // and should be generated using:
      // openssl passwd -1 "plaintextpassword"
      "users": ["deploy", "vagrant"]
    }
  },

  "vagrant" : {
    "exclusions" : [],
    "name" : "rails-postgres-redis1",
    "ip" : "192.168.50.4"
  },
  "rbenv":{
    "rubies": [
      "2.1.2"
    ],
    "global" : "2.1.2",
    "gems": {
      "2.1.2" : [
        {"name":"bundler"}
      ]
    }
  },
  "monit": {
    "notify_emails" : ["email@example.com"],
    "enable_emails" : false,
    "web_interface" : {
      // the plaintext monit username and password
      "allow" : ["your_username","your_password"]
    },
    "mailserver" : {
      "host" : "mailserver.example.com",
      "port" : "999",
      "username" : "your_username",
      "password" : "your_password",
      "hostname" : "the_hostname"
    }
  },
  "postgresql" : {
    "password" : {
      // this should be generated with:
      // openssl passwd -1 "plaintextpassword"
      // currently test
      "postgres" : "$1$mMK9HNoN$r42n7Q8fKsZabbknlT1Zt1"
    }
  },
  "run_list":
  [
    "role[server]",
    "role[nginx-server]",
    "role[postgres-server]",
    "role[rails-app]",
    "role[redis-server]",
  ]
}
```

As the passwords are visible is it safe to add like this?

If it should be in gitignore then at a later stage if we clone from the remote repo then we need to bootstrap the server from scratch as there is no node directory exists right?

Is there a better way or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need copy of node json files to bootstrap the node. Secure data should come from Chef Vault/Hashicorp Vault/any other secure storage. Non-confidential data can be part of recipe/wrapper recipe/role/environment/etc, which can be stored in the repository. If you really have data which are single node specific you can pass them using `-j` during the bootstrap process.

Comment: Based on above answer I assume node json is not needed in version control and can be easily recreated so can put on gitignore. But node json files are used when making updates to an existing server, like adding new roles/recipes.. right? In that case if I dont have the node json file do I need to bootstrap again? If so is it ok to do that on the already bootstrapped node?

Comment: Sorry, I have made one assumption (maybe one too far), are you using ChefServer of ChefZero? If the former, you should not care about nodes json files, just make regular backups of your ChefServer. In the case of the latter, you should keep all the essentials required for the bootstrap in the separate file passed as bootstrap options `-j`.

Comment: Yes am using chefzero. Sorry that I forget to mention that on the question. Thank you

Comment: You may consider some kind of encrypted git, like Keybase maybe (I am not sure how safe it is). It is probably as good as using ChefVault, you will have to pass/transfer/store the private key somehow. Or maybe just avoid public git hosting services? There is no silver bullet in this case.

Comment: Will have a look at keybase. Thank you.